# Python Pandas dont start on the first column

Tags: python, pandas

I loaded a CSV File using Python Pandas and want to drop every second column. I cant access the File from the first to last column. My CSV File has only one row with no captions. The origial file has about 1000 columns. For testing i use 12 columns. How to access the columns from the first to the last

I try to drop the first column by index. Later I want to iterate through it. I expect a index like 0 to 11 or index 1 to 12. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=0)

print(len(df.columns)) #returns 11 - expected: 12

df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Code works, but with index 0 it drops the second column instead of the first and index 2 drops the fourth one and so on...
Hope you can help me

Comment: I think you have to remove `index_col=0` from `read_csv`. This will assign first column of your dataset as index of dataframe

Comment: Try `df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", usecols=[i for i in range(12) if i%2==0])`

Comment: change `df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=0)` to `df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=None)`

Comment: @MEdwin - What is the use of keeping `index_col = None`. Default value of index_col is None

Answer (score 0):

I've edit my code. Not pretty but it works:

```
import pandas as pd

fileName = 'test.csv'

dummy = pd.read_csv(fileName)
length = len(dummy.columns)
del dummy

df = pd.read_csv(fileName, usecols=[i for i in range(length) if i%2==0])

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Thank you for your answers